# IS it possible to create a SAS token for ADLS GEN1

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I think I know the answer but just to be sure, is it possible to generate a SAS URI for ADLS GEN1?

What is the alternative? use Service principals?

Thnx,

Hennie

Comment: Hi @Hennie de Nooijer, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, SAS token doesn't support Azure Data Lake Gen1 for now. We can't generate a SAS URI for ADLS GEN1. It only support Blob, Queue, File and Table storage.

We can get this from SAS document [Delegate access with a shared access signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature#types-of-shared-access-signatures):

- **The service SAS delegates access to a resource in just one of the storage services: the Blob, Queue, Table, or File
  service**.

ADLS GEN1 only support access control lists(Access ACLs) to control the access permission to the files an folder.

Ref: [Access control in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control)

HTH.